# Update Angular Release Version Manually using CLI in environment.ts

Tags: angular, jenkins, angular-cli, versioning

In environment.ts we have release version. I want command to update minor version to update version from CLI so that i can use the same in Jenkins build job.

`export const environment = {
 …
 version: '0.0.0'
 …
};`

I want to update the minor version based on build number in Jenkins so that i can track the build version for Kits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"version:major": "npm version major && git push --follow-tags",
"version:minor": "npm version minor && git push --follow-tags",
"version:patch": "npm version patch && git push --follow-tags"
```

Please add this to scripts property of package.json

and before making a build you can run any of the command as per need,
lets say you want to update minor version by running `npm run version:minor`